# onclick Link hide img for ever same notification idea

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

I have page php & I have link to download file i need code show img one time
OR onclick Link (Download File) Hide img (nof1.gif)

Now I am replacing the image(nof1.gif) in an empty img (empty_img.png)
But when reloading the page the images Again

The idea to show the image only once

```html
<a   href="<?php echo base_url($l['admin_file']); ?>" target="_blank" >Download File </a> 



<img id="my_images" src="nof1.gif" style="width:40px;height:30px" 
  onclick="this.src='empty_img.png'; "
  >
```

or see the code There is an error and I do not know the solution!!!

```html
<html>

<button onclick="hideImage()'"> Remove img </button>
<img id="my_images" src="http://karachiairport.com.pk/images/data-section/airline/24-11.png">
<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // If cookie exist
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('image_clicked') > -1) {
        document.getElementById("my_images").src="http://www.1dmag.com/all_asset/img/no-image.png";
    }
 

    function hideImage() {
        document.getElementById("my_images").src="http://www.1dmag.com/all_asset/img/no-image.png";
        document.cookie = "image_clicked=true";
    }
});


</script>
```

Comment: how do you know that the guess/user has been downloaded the file?

Comment: If user pressed in the Link (Download File) ,So he download the File

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to use cookie

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('image_clicked') > -1) {
    document.getElementById("my_images").src="empty_img.png";
}

function hideImage() {
    document.getElementById("my_images").src="empty_img.png";
    document.cookie = "image_clicked=true";
}
```

Your html :

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url($l['admin_file']); ?>" onclick="hideImage()'" target="_blank" >Download File </a>
```

Comment: I run the code, only the img nof1 appears ,and does not change, i think the Function do not work!

Comment: I've edited, the onclick should be on the `a`. Can you watch your console to check any error ?

Comment: Same error  !! please see the Code There is an error and I do not know the solution!!

Comment: "message": "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 19,
  "colno": 18
}